# Korn Shell 93: Function Sends Non-null Value, But Calling Function Gets Null Value

Tags: function, shell, ksh

Readers:

I’ve spent a few days investigating the following incidents without successfully identifying the cause.  I’m writing in regard to ksh scripts I wrote to the ksh88 standards which have run for years on many HP-UX/PA-RISC and Solaris/Sparc platforms, and, even a few Linux/x86_64) platforms … until this week.  Upon running the scripts on CentOS 6.4/x86-x64 with Korn shell “Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01”, non-null values being returned to the Caller by some functions are retrieved by the Caller as null values.

Specifically, in the edited excerpts following, the variable ToDo always contains a value in fSendReqToSvr prior to fSendReqToSvr returning.  When fSendReqToSvr returns in fGetFileStatusFromSvr, Todo is assigned a null value.   The context of this script is as a child invoked by another ksh  script run from cron.  I’ve included the code reassigning stdout and stderr on the chance this is somehow significant.

What don’t I understand?

OS:
   CentOS-6.4 (x86-64) Development Installation
Korn Shell:
   Version: AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01
   Package: Ksh.x86_64 20120801-10.el6

---

```
...
function fLogOpen
{
   ...
   exec 3>$1   #C# Assigned Fd 3 to a log file

   #C# stdout and stderr are redirected to log file as insurance that 
   #C# no “errant” output from script (1700 lines) “escapes” from script.
   #C# stdout and stderr restored in fLogClose.
   exec 4>&1 
   exec 1>&3
   exec 5>&2
   exec 2>&3
   ...
}

...

#C# Invokes curl on behalf of caller and evaluates
function fSendReqToSvr
{
   typeset Err=0 ... \
           ToDo=CONTINUE ... \
           CL=”$2” ... 
   ...
   curl $CL > $CurlOutFFS 2>&1 &
   gCurlPId=$!
   while (( iSecsLeft > 0 )) ; do
      ...
      #C# Sleep N secs, check status of curl with “kill -0 $gCurlPId” 
      #C# and if curl exited, get return code from “wait $gCurlPId”.
      ...
   done
   ... 
   #C# Evaluate curl return code and contents of CurlOutFFS file to 
   #C# determine what to set ToDo to.
   ...
   print –n -– “$ToDo”   #C# ToDo confirmed to always have a value here
   return $Err
}

...

function fGetFileStatusFromSvr
{
   typeset Err=0 ... \
           ToDo=CONTINUE ... \
           ...
   ...
   ToDo=$( fSendReqToSvr “$iSessMaxSecs” “$CurlCmdLine” )
   Err=$?
   #C# ToDo contains null here
   ...

   return $Err
}
```

---

Comment: Try to provide a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The only thing that jumps out is that your code contains _typographical_ quotation marks (`”`) rather than regular ones (`"`), which may cause unexpected results (have you started using a different editor?); also, I assume you mean an empty string when you say "null value".

Comment: Code Review: ksh `print` does not require `-n` when the result is processed with `$( ... )`.  Ksh Command Substitution autochomps the result.

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that we don't see the code responsible for the `ToDo` result.

If this worked properly with *ksh88* before, you may have a problem if you don't have good tests for the individual functions, as *ksh88* and *ksh93* have many subtle and not so subtle differences.

Paradoxically, *ksh93* is easier to drop in as a replacement for `/bin/sh` (The mythical Bourne shell :-) than for *ksh88*.

The reason for this is that *ksh88* introduced extensions to the shell that were further enhanced **and changed** in *ksh93*.

One example that may touch on your question is arithmetic, which is limited to *integer arithmetic* in *ksh88* and got extended to *floating point* in *ksh93*.

Any utility expecting integer values can be fed results from arithmetic expressions in *ksh88*.
It may choke on the floating point results returned in *ksh93*.

Please supply a proper code sample that shows how the `ToDo` value is determined.

Comment: Since posting this question, I've had little time to devote to it.  mklement: Thanks for your comment.  Will post a MCVE when possible.  Langeveld: Thank you.  1. Regarding "... subtle and not so subtle differences ...", I have encountered same between implementations of 88', but, can you refer me to source(s) that describe such between 88' and 93'?  All: Until I can post MCVE, note that variable ToDo - in all output - always has a value ("CONTINUE", "NEXT_FILE", "NEXT_SVR", "EXIT") at the "print -n -- "$ToDo" line of fSendReqToSvr; That is to say, every log file confirms this.  Thanks again.

Comment: ksh88 has the problem that it was licensed to many different vendors, resulting in as many dialects when they started adding features (e.g., i18n).  ksh93 is an ongoing effort for 20 years now, with features getting added constantly, without a stable branch.  The ksh93 docs (see kornshell.com) has some overview on the ksh88 and ksh93 differences.